# installing archived (mvpart) package in newer R versions

Tags: r, devtools, install.packages

I am attempting to install the `mvpart` package which is archived.
I am using R version 4.3.1, RStudio 2023.6.1, and do have `RTools 4.3` installed on my PC.

I have attempted two alternative ways to install the package and both have produced errors.

**Method 1** was using devtools to retrieve the package from github

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("cran/mvpart")
```

[**The Error**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOhCE.png)

**Method 2** - Downloading from CRAN archive and installing

```
url <- "http://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mvpart/mvpart_1.6-2.tar.gz"
pkgFile<-"mvpart_1.6-2.tar.gz"
download.file(url = url, destfile = pkgFile)
install.packages("C:/Users/user/Downloads/mvpart_1.6-2.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

[**The Error**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOhCE.png)

Comment: Hi A Coult, welcome to SO. Please do not add code or error messages as an image for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2530121). Instead, add the code/error text either in a codeblock, or as a separate line starting with > in the case of error messages. Thanks

Comment: It looks like some kind of library incompatibility. It could be that: 1. your development environment is not set up properly or 2. the version of the mvpart package is incompatible with the version of R you have. To dig deeper into the issue, you can track down where the dependencies break down. From the error message you can tell that in the source file anova.c in package mvpart there is an include statement on line 6, presumably of header file rpart.h. Now the question is, is file rpart.h in the source of package mvpart, or does it come from the R or rtools includes? The compiler ...

Comment: The compiler complains about missing type Sint. This type should be defined in one of the header files, but for some reason the definition is not read in. This is possibly a big rabbit hole, so it may be simpler to focus on #1 and #2 above.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by getting the archived version of the `mvpart`
(mvpart_1.6-2.tar.gz), then use `R 4.1.0` to install it.